# Can't add foreign key after a index drop

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

So real quick what I did:

1. Realisted didn't need unique key but still foreign key
2. First needed to drop the foreign key

   `ALTER TABLE groups DROP FOREIGN KEY group_information_id`
3. Then dropped the unique key with

   `ALTER TABLE groups DROP INDEX group_information_id`
4. Now I want to add the foreign key again with

   `ALTER TABLE groups ADD CONSTRAINT group_information_id FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group_information.group_id`
5. Get the error (this is tanslated sorry if i'm not accurate, tell me if you don't understand):

> Can not add foreign key

Why is this happening, and how can I fix this so I can add a `foreign key`?

Engine `innodb` used

Comment: Why the SQL Server tag?

Comment: @Sander . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are specifically using.  But, the answer to your question is that foreign key relationships are properly made using unique/primary keys.

Comment: A foreign key always has to reference a key (either a primary key, or a unique constraint.)

Comment: @jarlh and Gordon Linoff Thank you for your answers, fixed the problem :D

Comment: @jarlh . . . Actually, MySQL doesn't require that (although I think all other databases do).  However, logically the relationships should be to unique or primary keys